# Overriding: Why in the below code Static method2() of Super class is called even if i'm using a reference of Sub class?

Tags: overriding

New to java, trying to learn basic concepts.

```
public class SuperClass{

    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method1");
        this.method2();
    }

    public static void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method2");
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{

    @Override
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("subclass method1");
        super.method1();
    }

    public static void method2() {
        System.out.println("subclass method2");     
    }
}

public class RefDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass subclass= new SubClass();
        subclass.method1();
    }
}
```

expected output:
subclass method1
superclass method1
superclass method2

actual output:
subclass method1
superclass method1
superclass method2

Comment: Static methods do not participate in virtual dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `this.method2()` (where you could also omit the `this.`) in SuperClass is actually the same as `SuperClass.method2()`, because the method is declared as static.

Your static method `method2` in the derived class is not overwriting the base class method and is therefore not invoked.